# Python Unit Tests fail as modules cannot import other modules in the package

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-wheel

We are having an issue with Unit Tests if the module under test needs to import another module from the same package, this is our directory structure:

```
Project_Dir:   
  src:
    package_dir:
        __init__.py
        my_module.py
        my_other_module.py   
  test:
    package_dir:
        __init__.py
        my_module_test.py
```

Test Code:

```
import unittest
from my_package.my_module import MyClass


class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

def test_multiple(self):
    test_obj = MyClass()
    test_obj.do_something()
```

Module Code:

```
import my_other_module


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_something(self):
        obj = my_other_module.MyOtherClass()
        obj.my_other_method()
        print("Called other method!")
```

We are using VS Code and pytest to actually run the tests in Azure pipelines (pytest is more convenient to generate reports/coverage).

The package is then built into a wheel with entry points used in ETL pipelines in Databricks, the wheels work absolutely fine (no import issues) so we have disabled/avoided testing modules that import others (not a long term solution), it seems we need to change the way the tests are executed or we have some structural issue that i am missing, help/pointers much appreciated.

Error from VS Code test discovery:

```
2023-12-20 11:33:15.311 [info] > "C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\unittestadapter\discovery.py
--udiscovery -v -s ./test/ -p *_test.py 2023-12-20 11:33:15.311 [info] cwd: c:\GitRepos\AzureDevops-Intellimax\Python-SampleProjects\Import Issue reproduce project 2023-12-20 11:33:15.510 [info] Test server connected to a client. 2023-12-20 11:33:15.514 [error] Unittest test discovery error for workspace:  c:\GitRepos\AzureDevops-Intellimax\Python-SampleProjects\Import Issue reproduce project   Failed to import test module: my_package.my_module_test Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 382, in
_find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 325, in
_get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)   File "c:\GitRepos\AzureDevops-Intellimax\Python-SampleProjects\Import Issue reproduce project\test\my_package\my_module_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src.my_package.my_module import MyClass   File "c:\GitRepos\AzureDevops-Intellimax\Python-SampleProjects\Import Issue reproduce project\src\my_package\my_module.py", line 1, in <module>
    import my_other_module ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_other_module'
```

Comment: This seems incorrect: you shouldn't be able to do `import my_other_module` in a package module if `my_other_module` is in the package in the first place.

Comment: Beyond that, having the same package name in both `src/` and `test/`, assuming both those roots are on `PYTHONPATH`, is bound to confuse things. I'd consider renaming the tests to `foo_tests` (or a subpackage `foo.tests`!)

Comment: Please fix your traceback (post it as code block). Also having an extra `src` folder is not the best way to structure a Python project.

Comment: If you want to check where is the path of the file running, just to double check, you can `print( os.getcwd() )`. This will give you a clue where your script is running. In this case, you need to add some relate imports, or move your test script to the main root of the project, and then import modules with `from src.module_name import function`

Comment: @AKX I see what you mean about the duplicate package folders - I have removed the subfolder in /test/ and experimenting with this. No luck as yes.

Comment: @KlausD. can you describe what you mean by "extra" src folder?

Comment: @JoseM.González I have looked at many options for relative imports, obviously this isn't possible in my source files as the script/wheel won't function correctly, so do you mean to add imports in the test folder? Thankyou,

Comment: @AlanBlyth The think is... you are not importing your library because you are in the wrong directory. If you move your test.py into your src folder, youll be able to import it. Tests shouldnt have it's own folder, they need to be ignored in .gitignore file and they should be in the root of the folder for good practices. Anyways, what I was suggesting is to check where the file you are running is placed, with getcwd() and from there you can figure out how to import that module. Anyways, the better option is to place your test.py in the src/ folder and import from there the module.

Comment: @JoseM.González adding tests to .gitignore doesn't seem like a good solution - how are they found in CICD pipelines? I found a good solution and will post an answer here for others.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem (hopefully a long term solution) by following this guidance: https://pytest.org/en/7.4.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules

Putting all my Tests into a /tests/ folder outside of /src/ and switching to pytest which seems to solve some import problems 'magically', i'm not installing before running so there is potentially some further improvements, but it's in a good place now.

Finding this additiong to the pyproject.toml unlocked the issue:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = [
    "--import-mode=importlib",
]
```

Honestly this is seriously headachey - we need an equivalent to Maven that will just generate a good project structure for us, maybe pip could do this...